# Вывод разных querisets в Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Возможно немного некорректно вопрос сформулировал. В общем не понимаю каким образом вывести с помощью DRF различные коллекции объектов. Пытаюсь понять по аналогии с django views. Мне надо вывести список всех мест, список самых популярных и список - выбор редакции.

```
def places_list(request):
    places = Places.objects.all()
    editor_places = Places.objects.filter(editor_choice = True )
    popular_places = Places.objects.filter(most_popular = True )

    return render (request, "places/places_list.html", {"places": places,
                                                       "editor_places": editor_places,
                                                       "popular_places": popular_places,
                                                    })
```

И дальше уже в шаблоне отображаю допустим 3 таблицы с нужными мне параметрами.

Делаю API

**serializer.py**

```
class PlaeceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = (
            'main_photo',
            'name',               
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class PlacesListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaeceSerializer
```

Так у меня формируется коллекция json содержащая все объекты. Как правильно делать выборку, во views.py или же как то работать на фронте с полученными данными? Поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста. Желательно с объяснением сути процесса )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При работе с DRF, один запрос - один результат, что немного расходится со стандартной django.

Для фильтрации, в документации DRF выделен [свой раздел](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

Один из вариантов, с использованием [django-filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend):

Установим `django-filter` и добавим его в `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
pip install django-filter
```

Добавим бэкэнд фильтров в настройки:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

**Или**, вы можете добавить его только в нужный вью:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    ...
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Так-же вы можете указать список полей, по которым необходимо фильтровать, указав `filter_fields`:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('category', 'in_stock')
```

Пример использования:

```
http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&in_stock=True
```

Информация взята из документации [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо!